# Camera preview problem in Android

Tags: android

I have some problem with my Android code. I need to put camera preview in my app but just on small part of screen. I found on net example with inheritance of SurfaceView but that example cover all space on screen. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Define your own xml layout and than add class in which you code for camera application.

For example:

suppose your class name is : cameraDemo.java
Package Name is : com.cameraDemo

than your .xml file is look like

android:layout_width=
android:layout_height=
/>